# Bank ATM Login in Python

Tags: python, authentication

This is an ATM program with basic functions. After new user registration, the user is able to proceed to the login function and bank operations after. However, existing users can't proceed to bank operations after login as the program just stops running. How can I fix that?

```
.....
def init():
    print('Welcome to Esther Bank')
    
    have_account = int(input('Do you have an account with us? \n 1 (yes) 2 (no) \n'))

    if(have_account == 1):
        login()
    elif(have_account == 2):
        register()
    else:
        print('You have selected an invalid option')
        init()


#user login
def login():
    print('***Login to your account***')

    user_acct = int(input('Enter your account number: \n'))
    user_pwd = input('Enter your password: \n')

    for acct_no, user in database.items():
        if user_acct == acct_no:
            if user_pwd == user[3]:
                bank_operations(user)
        else: 
            print('Invalid account or password, try again')
            login()

#user registration
def register():
    print('********Register******')
    email = input('Enter your email address: \n')
    f_name = input('Enter your first name: \n')
    l_name = input('Enter your last name: \n')
    password = input('Create a strong password: \n') 

    account_number = generate_acct_number()
    balance = 0

    database[account_number] = [f_name, l_name, email, password, balance]
    
    print('Welcome %s, your account has been created \n' %f_name)
    print('Your account number is %s \n' %account_number)
    print('Ensure your keep your account number and password safe')
    login()


#bank operations
def bank_operations(user):
    print('Welcome %s %s' %(user[0], user[1]))
    print('What would you like to do? \n')
    print('1. Deposit')
    
.....
```

Comment: what do You mean stops working? does it throw an error? gives any output?

Comment: It doesn't throw any error. It just stops running.

Comment: try adding a break after You call `bank_operations()`

Comment: also that else statement isn't really properly placed: it will call login for each user in database that doesn't match account number

Comment: Yeah, that was what I wanted it to do. So they can try to login again

Comment: yes but it will call login the amount of times there are users in the dict/database that don't match account number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would redefine Your login function:

```py
def login():
    print('***Login to your account***')

    user_acct = int(input('Enter your account number: \n'))
    user_pwd = input('Enter your password: \n')

    if user_acct not in database.keys():
        print('Invalid account or password, try again')
        login()
        return

    if database[user_acct][3] == user_pwd:
        bank_operations(database[user_acct])
    else:
        print('Invalid account or password, try again')
        login()
        return
```

first check if the user actually is in the database and if not call the function again and stop the current one, if the user is in database just check if passwords match

EDIT: made some more improvements

Comment: Added the final improvements so now it should work

Comment: Edited again, this time I changed back to the function You were calling